# convert characters to numeric range in r?

Tags: python, r

I have a simple problem. I have set of vector (characters). I want to convert them into numeric along with colon operator.

```
a <- c("10:20", "25:30")
print (a)
```

[1] "10:20" "25:30"

```
as.numeric(a)
```

[1] NA NA

Warning message:

NAs introduced by coercion

This is the error i'm getting.

**The expected output is**

```
10:20
20:30
```

I tired this but did not work the way i expected

```
strapply(a, "(\\d+):(\\d+)")
```

Comment: Is there a good reason why you used the python tag?

Comment: You could have `start` and `end` vectors in a dataframe: `a |> tibble() |> separate(a, into = c("start", "end"))`

Comment: I have to compare two columns, which mean every row contains start and end positions. But good one. Thanks for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to know what you mean by the expected output. Taking you literally, you want the strings converted to calls:

```r
 lapply(a, function(x) as.call(parse(text = x))[[1]])
#> [[1]]
#> 10:20
#>
#> [[2]]
#> 25:30
```

My guess is that this is not what you meant, and instead you want the strings to be evaluated, in which case you *could* do:

```r
lapply(a, function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#>
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

However, this is fairly unsafe, since it would be easy to write a malicious string that caused problems on your computer if the data was not always checked for safety beforehand.

A safer way to do this would be

```r
lapply(strsplit(a, ":"), function(x) x[1]:x[2])
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

which will throw an error if the string isn't in the correct format rather than running arbitrary code on your computer.

Comment: The very first code is what i was looking for. Thanks for your reply. Could you please explain the code?

Comment: `parse` converts the string to an R expression, and `as.call` converts it to a call. You extract the first element of the call to get the actual bit you need. Because this isn't a vectorized operation it needs to be vectorized with `lapply`